# why the webcam is showing anything in opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I am making a gui with a button to make webcam on and off. and it is working but when i open it again after closing it then its shows only black screen.

how to resolve this issue.

Here is my code. my whole code is huge so i posted on the webcam part here.

> i updated my code .......................

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
webcam = None
WEBCAM_SIZE = (280, 200)

def read_frame(imgbox):

    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, WEBCAM_SIZE)
            image = Image.fromarray(frame)
            imgbox.image.paste(image)
        webcam.after(20, read_frame, imgbox)

def stop_webcam(event):
    global webcam

    if webcam:
        webcam.destroy()
        webcam = None
        cap.release()
def start_webcam():
    global webcam
    cap.open()
    if webcam is None:
        cap.isOpened()
        webcam = tk.Toplevel()
        #webcam = tk.lift()
        webcam.attributes("-topmost", True) #it keep the window on top of others
        webcam.geometry('{}x{}+5+520'.format(WEBCAM_SIZE[0], WEBCAM_SIZE[1]))
        webcam.overrideredirect(1)
        imgbox = tk.Label(webcam)
        imgbox.pack()
        imgbox.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.new('RGB',WEBCAM_SIZE,(0,0,0)))
        imgbox.config(image=imgbox.image)
        #webcam.bind('', stop_webcam)
        read_frame(imgbox)
cap_btn = ttk.Button(frame, image=web, width=20, command=change_w)
cap_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
cap_btn.image = web
def change_w():
        if cap_btn.image == web:
            start_webcam()

            cap_btn.config(image=web2)
            cap_btn.image = web2
        else:
            stop_webcam(None)

            cap_btn.config(image=web)
            cap_btn.image = web
web = PhotoImage(file='webcam.png')
web2 = PhotoImage(file='bl.png')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Either do not call `cap.release()` in `stop_webcam()` or call `cap.open()` in `start_webcam()`.

Comment: @acw1668 showing error `VideoCapture.open() missing required argument 'index' (pos 1)` when putting cap.open() in start button

Comment: You need to pass the same argument when you create `VideoCapture()`.